# How to steup VSCode tunnel as user service in Windows 11?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The result of command `code tunnel service install` show the prompts. I type my password and press the `Enter` key. But nothing happened.
[image]

I couldn't find a solution for it.

Comment: I tried using [winsw](https://github.com/winsw/winsw) to wrap the command `code tunnel service internel-run`. But it shows that `error error starting service dispatcher: IO error in winapi call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download the windows x64 code-cli(**not vscode desktop**), and run the command again. The problem is solved. This seems to be a magical problem with vscode desktop (version 1.74.1).
I can't press the "Caps Lock" key when typing my username!

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow 's community! Please, close the questions as soon as you could. Thanks!